# How to separate strings and pass tokens to methods

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

For a class I need to take a text file and make a binary tree for all words and the lines that they occur on. I have the binary tree working for basic pre-made strings, but I am having trouble delimiting the words and telling what line number I am on.

```
    getline(MyFile, c);
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((b.size() == 0) && ((c[i] == ',') || (c[i] == ' ') || (c[i] == '.') || (c[i] == ';') || (c[i] == '\0')));
        else
            if ((b.size() > 0) && ((c[i] == ',') || (c[i] == ' ') || (c[i] == '.') || (c[i] == ';') || (c[i] == '\0')))
            {
                K1.AddWordOrIncriment(b, LineCounter);
                b.clear();
            }
            else
                b.push_back(c[i]);
    }
    LineCounter++;
```

This is how I'm trying to do it, I've seen other posts on ways to do it but honestly they seem beyond my comprehension right now and I'd rather not just copy something I don't understand.

Comment: so you are using binary-search-tree only for search?
If yes then why not  `Trie`?

Answer (score 2):

Use std::strtok to split a line with multiple delimiters into multiple strings

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);

// Convert string to char* so that std::strtok could be used later
char *cstr = new char[line.length() + 1];
std::strcpy(cstr, line.c_str());
vector<string> words;

// split line into multiple strings using multiple delimiters
char* ptr = std::strtok(cstr, " -.,;");
while (ptr)
{
    string str(ptr);
    words.push_back(str);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, " -.,;");
}
delete[] cstr;
```

Comment: You don't have to copy std::string into separate char array buffer,  `char *ptr = const_cast<char*>( line.data() );` should be enough. Standard guaranty std::string data must be an array.